# How to construct a sequence of rational weights that sum to 1 for any real weights that sum to 1?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Suppose I have $p=(p_1,p_2,\ldots p_n)$, $p_i\geq 0$ and $\sum^n_{i=1}p_i=1$. How do I construct a sequence that satisfies
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\Big(p_1(t),p_2(t),\ldots,p_n(t)\Big)=p,\  t\in\mathbb{N}
$$
where $\sum^n_ip_i(t)=1$ for all $t$.

---

I get that I can construct such a sequence for any $p$ given the definition of real number. However, how to make sure that $\sum^n_ip_i(t)=1$ for all $t$ holds for such sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only works for $n \ge 2$. Since you speak about a *sequence*, the variable $t$ seems to denote an integer. You do not mention whether you assume $p_i > 0$, but I guess you tacitly do.

For $i = 1,\ldots,n-1$ let $(p_i(t))_{t \in \mathbb N}$ be sequences of rational numbers such $p_i \ge p_i(t) > 0$ and $p_i(t) \to p_i$as $t \to \infty$. Then the $p_n(t) = 1 -\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} p_i(t)$ are rational numbers such that $p_n(t) \ge 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} p_i = p_n > 0$. Clearly $p_n(t) \to p_n $as $t \to \infty$.